# strcmp cannot convert 'char**' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Tags: c++, arduino, strcmp, platformio

Porting code for arduino nano to esp8266

```
    // list of fields that must be quoted in JSON convertion
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_CMD[]         = "CMD";
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_BAT[]         = "BAT";
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_SMOKEALERT[]  = "SMOKEALERT";
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_SWITCH[]      = "SWITCH";
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_PIR[]         = "PIR";
     char RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_RFDEBUG[]     = "RFDEBUG";
     char* RFLINK_FIELD_STRING[] = {
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_CMD,
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_BAT,
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_SMOKEALERT,
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_SWITCH,
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_PIR,
      RFLINK_FIELD_NAME_RFDEBUG,
      "\0" // do not remove this mark the end of the array
    };
```

The function that is giving problems:

```
    /**
     * check wether a given string is in a array of strings
     */
    bool RfLinkIsStringInArray(char *buffer, char* strArray[]) {
      int i = 0;
      int j;

      while((strArray + i) != '\0') {

        j = strcmp(buffer, (strArray + i++));
        if((j==0)) return true;
      }

  return false;
}
```

```
In function 'bool RfLinkIsStringInArray(char*, char**)':
 error: cannot convert 'char**' to 'const char*' for 
argument '2' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
     j = strcmp(buffer, (strArray + i++));
```

Comment: That code looks a lot like https://github.com/jit06/RflinkToJsonMqtt/blob/a49f82e438b4b6e60eb390737a28739661378e7d/Rflink.cpp#L126-L137.

Comment: That is where the code comes from. But  https://github.com/jit06/RflinkToJsonMqtt/blob/a49f82e438b4b6e60eb390737a28739661378e7d/Rflink.cpp#L126-L137 is for an arduino nano with ethernet shield. I'm trying to run it on a esp8266. Got most to compile already, but I'm stuck on the strcmp_P in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

`strArray` is an array of string pointers, terminated by a pointer to a zero-length string (why not a NULL pointer?). An array itself decays into a pointer to its first element. You need to dereference the array pointer to access the individual string pointers so you can pass them to `strcmp()` until you reach that terminator, eg:

```c
bool RfLinkIsStringInArray(char *buffer, char* strArray[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (*(strArray + i) != "\0") // <- note the *
    {
        j = strcmp(buffer, *(strArray + i++)); // <- note the *
        if (j == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, just use normal array syntax (which works on array pointers) instead of manual pointer arithmetic syntax:

```c
bool RfLinkIsStringInArray(char *buffer, char* strArray[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (strArray[i] != "\0")
    {
        j = strcmp(buffer, strArray[i++]);
        if (j == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, it is possible to eliminate the `i` and `j` variables completely:

```c
bool RfLinkIsStringInArray(char *buffer, char* strArray[])
{
    while (*strArray != "\0")
    {
        if (strcmp(buffer, *strArray++) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That being said, there is no guarantee that two different `"\0"` string literals in code will point to the same memory address at runtime. Some compilers do merge duplicate strings, but that is very compiler-specific behavior. You should not rely on that. You need to either use `strlen(...) == 0` to detect the terminating zero-length string, or better to use a NULL pointer instead.

Comment: "\0"  is different from 0. Adding a nullptr at the end of the char* strArray[] were the better solution, though.

Comment: @datafiddler thanks, I updated my answer. I have never seen anyone terminate an array by "\0" rather than null.

Comment: Wel, the original code for the array was including PROGMEM (https://github.com/jit06/RflinkToJsonMqtt/blob/a49f82e438b4b6e60eb390737a28739661378e7d/Rflink.cpp#L126-L137) PROGMEM instructs the arduino compiler to store the variable in flash, rather then in sram. Platformio does not allow that, that is why I removed it. But that is probably the reason not to use a NULL pointer at te end.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: `*strArray != "\0"`might always be true, as it's comparing addresses, and its not sure, "\0" will exist only once. I suggest `(strlen(*strArray) != 0)`